# Cannot create new Object from Maven dependency

Tags: java, class, maven, intellij-idea, ebean

I'm trying to make an Ebean ServerConfig as explained here: 
http://www.avaje.org/ebean/getstarted_programmatic.html

But, when in my project I create a new ServerConfig object, I cannot access the methods in it.

```
package controller;

import com.avaje.ebean.config.ServerConfig;

public class ormConfig {
    ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
    config.setName("mysql");
}
```

No expection, no hint from the IDE. Only an error from the compiler:

> "Error:(14, 19) java: <identifier> expected"

https://gist.github.com/Szil/f65bc2d7180d2ae49ad5

Included the pom.xml in the Gist.

I have no idea where the problem is. A bit newbie in Maven and not exactly expert in Java, but simply creating a new object shouldn't be a problem most of the time.

Comment: And where is that error pointing to?

Comment: Nevermind, the answer : "You can't have arbitrary code directly inside a class."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have arbitrary code directly inside a class. Only fields and methods declarations. Code like

```
 config.setName("mysql");
```

must go into a method or a constructor.

Also, classes conventionally start with an uppercase letter in Java:

```
public class OrmConfig {
    ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();

    OrmConfig() {
        config.setName("mysql");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Oh god, totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the config inside a constructor or a method as you cannot do this elsewhere. For example:

```
import com.avaje.ebean.config.ServerConfig;

public class OrmConfig {

    private ServerConfig config;

    public OrmConfig() {
        config = new ServerConfig();
        config.setName("mysql");
    }
}
```

By the way - which IDE are you using because this is definitely showing up in Intellij. :)

Comment: Strange, I'm using IntelliJ and just only said "Cannot resolve symbol".